# How can room sized amethyst geodes form commonly?

Tags: science-based, earth-like, geology

I would like my Earth-like planet to have a very strange feature. Near spherical amethyst geodes with diameters up to 11 meters - the size of a large room, form commonly underground at depths from 30 - 50 meters. How can this happen? I want as little effect as possible on how habitable the planet remains. I'm not an expert geologist and so I was unsure of the parameters and requirements for such a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amethyst forms geodes naturally, and **at small sizes** they tend to be round-(ish).
However, their shape is not strongly bound to be spherical. It would be better to describe them as a blunt blob.

Here is [the largest Amethyst Geode on Earth](http://www.geologypage.com/2017/01/worlds-largest-amethyst-geode.html) at 3.27m tall but less than 1m wide:
[image]

The formation of Amethyst Geodes requires two steps.

1. a basaltic lava bed, with a void/bubble in it.
2. followed by geological stability and a lot of time. In effect, the void inside the lava "fossilizes" with mineral-rich water that leaches from the basalt surrounding it. If the region is not very geologically quiet, an earthquake will crack the lava bad, preventing the geode formation. Instead the mineralization will occur along the cracks.

[This process](https://sciencing.com/geodes-5377367.html) takes many hundreds of thousands of years, or a few million years.

So: you need a mechanism that will make for many , **huge** Amethyst Geodes. Close to the surface.

- You need a volcanic event that makes a lava bed of *at least* as thick as your geodes must be, and preferably many times thicker.
- You need some mechanism that makes neat, huge, spherical voids in the lava as it cools. Maybe a huge pumpkin-type plant trapped in the lava? The organic residue will rot away rapidly, leaving a suitable void?
- You cannot have too many of these voids near each other. There is just so much mineral that can be leached from the basalt! The solid rock needs to be hundreds to thousands of times the volume of the voids.
- You then need to leave this lava bed stable for a long enough time. For something as huge as 11 m across, budget for not millions but a few hundreds of millions of years.

Small P.s.
Not relevant for your scenario, but geodes come in all sorts of flavors. Amethyst is just the type one gets when the minerals contain significant traces of Iron.

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely PERFECT!